# Giving connection to the controls in objective C(XCode) leads to NSUnknownKeyException

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Xcode and objective C programming.Please help me to resolve the following problem.

After adding the Textfield and buttons i tried to give connection for view and controller and it leads to the following error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[<UIViewController 0x3b13bb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
>   this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key txtUsername.

and the debugger gets terminated.It happens only after adding the view - controller connection.

I searched google but found that class name should be specified exactly under Class Identifiers,but i have specified it and even then i am getting this error.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes I have changed its name from txtUserID to txtUsername ,         thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly caused because of changing the name of the variable that you have connected in your XIB file. If this is the case you can check the bottom right of your interface builder(in xcode 3) and if you see a warning sign than you will know that something has went wrong. You can then reconnect the outlet in your interface builder and everything will be good to go.

Comment: I think you have done some thing else wrong, can you check your connections and variables in your class once again.

Comment: And one more thing at the left bottom corner **GDB:Interrupted* this message is displayed.

Comment: Hey you can delete your comments here and just leave the last one

Comment: Now I got the solution.While giving the connections I didnt select the class name in the View Identity Inspector window. Thanks a lot robin, for your kind help